# Multiple instances from clicking multiple times of the same button before it's launched

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Sometimes when my app runs slower, the user is able to click on the button from which the intent is launched multiple times. I heard that this maybe a bug that's fixed in ICS - is that true? Or do I have to manage launch mode for every single intent I start.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Setting the proper launch mode seems to be less of a hack than messing with the buttons. If there's no other option I guess "singleTop" in android-manifest activity launch mode will do.

Answer (score 0):

Add some simple debouncing:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private boolean wasButtonPressed = false;

void onResume() {
    super onResume();
    wasButtonPressed = false;
}

void onClick( View view ) {
    if( !wasButtonPressed ) {
        wasButtonPressed = true;
        startActivity( ....
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable the button when you are performing a long operation an makes it enabled after performing oporation to response for user click. You are performing a long operation on the onClick method, the os will stack all your user clicks,witch will be fowarded asynchronously this is not a bug. You can show a Progress dialog to notify the user for long operation. A quick fix will be to disable the button until the previous click is totally consumed.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View aView) {
        int id = aView.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.yourButton:
                aView.setEnabled(false);
               // add your own implementation
                aView.setEnabled(true);
                break;

            default:

                break;
        }

    }
```